# Transfer wallet to new server

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, installation

I have been running a bitcoin app in an old server. I need to move everything to a new server but my question is this: is there a way I can transfer my bitcoin wallet (bitcoin core) to the new server with a clean O/S installation without losing the tx history from my old server's wallet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just shut down the bitcoin app on the old server, copy the `wallet.dat` file to the new server, then start the bitcoin app on the new server. Don't remove anything from the old installation until you 100% confirm that the new installation works.